# Modbus Tcp For silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, tcp, plc, modbus

Original Question:

I'm looking for a silverlight library or example that shows me how to use the silverlight framework to connect to a modbus device by tcp.

I've found multiple libraries using the tcpClient `from system.net.sockets.tcpclient` but this namespace is not availeble in silverlight. So .net librarys won't do the trick

also, just for background information, i'm building a windows phone app, and I have allready looked into the example " using sockets in windowsphone"  on the msdn site [(Link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202858%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

---

Edit 1:

After some time programming, I am able to write the holding registers of the modbus device using the `System.net.sockets` library only. Problem is, i get a return byte from my modbus device. Also, i had a receive function to read registers on the modbus device which also returns bytes.

I used to catch bytes like this (using `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient`:

```
    // Making a new netwerk stream named ns
    NetworkStream ns;

    // Function for receiving
    protected override int ReceiveByte()
    {
        // Check for byte, if byte, read it and put it in a byte array.
        if (ns.DataAvailable)
            return ns.ReadByte();

        // If there's no data left, return;
        else
            return -1;
    }
```

What I'm asking for is these things:
1. Is there a function in the `System.net.Sockets` that has the same functionality as the Networkstream.Readbyte?
2. If there is no function able to do the same thing. Are there otherways, and if so, are there examples, or can someone get me started?

Thanks :)

---

Comment: What version are you targeting? Sockets can only be used for applications targeting WP7.1(a.k.a. Mango) or higher.

Comment: @DragosCalin i'm targeting WP7.1 and higher :) so that is not the problem. The problem lies in that all the libs that i can find rely on the system.net.sockets.tcpclient.. which phone 7.1 doesn't have

Comment: I've seen this approach before and I'll ask the question again - why go direct to modbus from a phone??  PLCs are a highly specialized and primitive part of infrastructure.  Why not pick a more suitable point in that infrastructure to interface - something like a local HMI/server?  This makes the whole system much more robust, flexible, and secure.  It also massively simplifies your task.

Comment: @J... It certainly will make it easier and robust. Except for the fact that my assignment is to communicate from the phone, to the plc directly without interference of other devices (even if they are in the same network). So its not that this way is impossible. Its just not desirable, and for the protocol (as far as i can look into this)  it should be able to work as long as it has a tcp connection. The data handling (in modbus format) is not depending on the sockets.tcpclient. The connection on the other hand is :(

Comment: @BartTeunissen  ...assignment?  Is this homework?

Comment: @J... No, it is not. Its a assignment @ my job.

Comment: @BartTeunissen Then I re-iterate that this is not a recommended approach for any sort of professional/industrial PLC installation.  Modbus is not made for this, it is insecure, and it compromises the integrity of your system.  A tiny micro-PC costs a fraction of what a PLC does.  Unless this PLC is for fun and games, I really recommend the PLC<->PC<->THEWORLD architecture.

Comment: I'm supposed to make a proof of concept, that it is possible to control a PLC device with a mobile phone (on three different platforms, IOS, WindowsPhone, and Android). So if it fails, ill just take that into my conclusion. But first, i need to get a connection working, before i can conclude anything.

Comment: @BartTeunissen of course it is possible.  The real question on your mind should be - "What is the best approach here"? Otherwise you end up doing a boatload of work, only to have to scrap it all and do it right a second time instead of properly considering your system design in the first place.  Get your automation working with OPC on a real data server first.  Connecting a phone and a PC is miles easier, then, and you get all the benefits of secure/encrypted communication, process isolation, error checking/handling, and lots of high level tools to make the job go MUCH more quickly and easily.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Socket directly, not a TcpClient.  The code ends up a little more verbose, but it's not all that bad.  If you want to use an existing set of Modbus code, you could just create a TcpClient replacement that has the same interface as the FFx/CF version.

**EDIT**

This is a bit weird as you've somewhat changed the question with your edit, going from using modbus to how to receive a byte with a raw Socket.  The `Socket` class exposes a synchronous `Receive` and an asynchronous `BeginReceive` method.

You can also create a `NetworkStream` from a `Socket` via one of the `NetworkStream` constructors.

Comment: Oké can i find a example somewhere of how to use the interface as the FFx/CF version?